# Azure API Management - How to set the VNET/SubNet using Azure CLI?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-cli

I have created my VNET & SubNet as mentioned below

```
RESOURCE_GROUP="POC-RG"
LOCATION="westus"
APIMNAME="poc-apim-98"
PUBLISHER="Demo"
PUBLISHEREMAIL="myemail@demo.com"
SKU="Premium"
VNETNAME="app-vnet"
APITYPE="External"

az network vnet create \
  --resource-group ${RESOURCE_GROUP} \
  --name ${VNETNAME} \
  --location ${LOCATION}

az network vnet subnet create \
--resource-group ${RESOURCE_GROUP} \
--vnet-name ${VNETNAME} \
--name apim \
--address-prefixes 10.0.5.0/24
```

and I want to provision the Azure API Management in the apim subnet created above

```
az apim create --name ${APIMNAME} -g ${RESOURCE_GROUP} -l ${LOCATION} --sku-name ${SKU} --publisher-email ${PUBLISHEREMAIL} --publisher-name ${PUBLISHER} --virtual-network ${APITYPE}
```

Looks like Azure CLI does not take the subnet parameter while creating the APIM, how do I set the subnet and create the Azure API Management using azure cli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right. For some reason `az apim create` does not provide option to input a subnet reference of a VNET.

You have 2 options:

- Use ARM template. Refer [Create an API Management service in External Virtual Network](https://azure.microsoft.com/resources/templates/201-api-management-create-with-external-vnet/) for sample template.

```
az group deployment create --resource-group <my-resource-group> --template-uri https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/master/201-api-management-create-with-external-vnet/azuredeploy.json
```

Or,

- Use `az resource` command to add subnet reference after you create APIM.

```
az apim create --name ${APIMNAME} -g ${RESOURCE_GROUP} -l ${LOCATION} --sku-name ${SKU} --publisher-email ${PUBLISHEREMAIL} --publisher-name ${PUBLISHER} --virtual-network ${APITYPE}

$apimResourceId = az apim show -n ${APIMNAME} -g ${RESOURCE_GROUP} --query 'id' -o json

$subnetResourceId = az network vnet subnet show -g ${RESOURCE_GROUP} -n apim --vnet-name ${VNETNAME} --query 'id' -o json

az resource update --ids $apimResourceId --set properties.virtualNetworkConfiguration.subnetResourceId=$subnetResourceId
```

Comment: Good solution. Just to to share my experience: at least in case `--vitual-network=Internal`, it will be ignored at APIM creation (I guess because a subnet is required), the solution will be to set both properties together like `az resource update --ids $apimResourceId --set properties.vistualNetworkType=Internal properties.virtualNetworkConfiguration.subnetResourceId=$subnetResourceId`.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
As this is using both two CLI, you might have to do both login and select subscription for both ways

```
az login
Connect-AzAccount

$apim = Get-AzApiManagement -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $APIMName
$apimResourceId = az apim show -n ${APIMName} -g ${ResourceGroup} --query 'id' -o json
$subnetResourceId = az network vnet subnet show -g ${ResourceGroup} -n $Subnet --vnet-name ${VnetName} --query 'id' -o json
$virtualNetwork = New-AzApiManagementVirtualNetwork -SubnetResourceId $subnetResourceId
$apim.VpnType = "Internal"
$apim.VirtualNetwork = $virtualNetwork
Set-AzApiManagement -InputObject $apim
```